# Web Audio filter node popping

Tags: web, audio, filter, web-audio-api

I am getting popping when modulating a filter nodes frequency with an LFO when the filter frequency bottoms out.

I suspect this is due to the amplitude not being at the time of cutoff.  Is it necessary to modulate the gain as well?  I was hoping not to have to and I'm not really sure how I would anyway.

Edit: forgot link to example code http://jsfiddle.net/hyf5N/

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext();

var lfo = context.createOscillator();

lfo.frequency.value = 10;

var saw = context.createOscillator();
saw.type = 'sawtooth';

var filter = context.createBiquadFilter();
filter.type = 'lowpass';

var gain = context.createGainNode();
gain.gain.value = 500;

saw.connect(filter);
lfo.connect(gain);
gain.connect(filter.frequency);

filter.connect(context.destination);

lfo.start(0);
saw.start(0)
```

Comment: I think your question would be much clearer with some code.   Furthermore, you might be better off asking on [http://dsp.stackexchange.com](http://dsp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: yeah, sorry for got to link to code.  its there now.  I didn't know about the dsp subdomain, ill check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting pops (would have to analyze waveform to see exactly why) because your LFO is modulating the frequency from -490 to 510.  (freq.value = 10, + LFO ([-1,1]) * 500.)  I expect the negative frequency is causing an issue.

If you want it to modulate from 0 to 1kHz, you set the frequency.value to 500, and the gain.value to 500.  (The key here is that an oscillator is going to go from -1 to 1, not 0 to 1.)

Code for a rectifier:

```
var waveshaper = audioContext.createWaveShaper();
var curve = new Float32Array(65536);
for (var i=0; i<32768; i++)
    curve[i] = 0.0;
for (var i=32768; i<65536; i++)
    curve[i] = (i/32768) - 1;
waveshaper.curve = curve;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer Chris.  It seems to me that it is a common use case to want to set an lfo to modulate the filter cutoff and then be able to adjust the filter cutoff to a position where the modulation hits or goes below zero to get create a intermittent pulsing effect.  All this while keeping the LFO frequency quite low.  Would there be a way to make the filter frequency modulation bottom out at 0 while keeping the amplitude and frequency of the modulation the same (in this instance an amplitute of 500 at 10hz).

Comment: You mean, have the LFO have a zero value for half the wave cycle, and a pulse the rest of the cycle?

Sure - use a waveshaper node in between the LFO and the .  Create a large curve (65k), and have the first half of the array set to zero, and the second half of the array set to ((arrayIndex/32k) - 1).  This creates a rectifier, which will keep the output from going negative. I use this technique (for a different purpose) in the AutoWah in my input effects demo on webaudiodemos.appspot.com.

Comment: That should have been "use a waveshaper node in between the LFO and filter cutoff."  Added rectifier code above.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to make the waveshaper work for me since I didn't want to bottom out the lfo signal at 0 but rather make it so the modulation wouldn't push the filter frequency below 0.  I ended up using a scriptProcessorNode like so

```
modulationProcessor = this.context.createScriptProcessor(4096);
modulationProcessor.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
  // bottom out frequency modulation at filter.frequency == 0 to avoid popping
  var input = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
  var output = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
  var frequency = filter.frequency.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    output[i] = (input[i] + frequency) > 0 ? input[i] : input[i] - (input[i] + frequency);
  }
}
```

It isn't perfect since it seems like if you are adjusting the filter frequency a lot you can still get popping sometimes.  I think it is because the filter value can get stale while the buffers are being written.  It seems to work fine if you aren't live editing the filter frequency though.